# Can't get RTL8125B working on 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, realtek

So I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on a computer with the new RTL8125B Realtek network card and I cannot get the network to work.

I was very suprised since this is supposed to be the new feature of the 5.4 kernel (I have 5.4.0-26-generic installed).

Does anyone have any idea on how to get it working? Thank you.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 04)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1043:87d7]
Kernel modules: r8169
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] [1002:67df] (rev e7)

$ dmesg | grep -i r8169
[    0.911236] r8169 0000:06:00.0: unknown chip XID 641
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I added the output. In the meantime I tried:
https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software
to no avail

Comment: I made a typo, please post the output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

Comment: done :) Thank you for the help.

Comment: Now please add output of `dmesg | grep -i r8169`

Comment: Please try `sudo apt-get install r8125-dkms`

Comment: @Pilot6 it seems that we are on the right track

Comment: @Raffles I have no internet connection in the Ubuntu system, and now I am waiting for a usb wifi dongle to be able to do similar things... I will let you know, thank you for the help, right now I can say the package is not installed yet

Comment: It looks like this specific chip is not supported by this kernel yet.

Comment: I had the feeling... I will wait for the new kernel then. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `rtl8125b` support has been added to the `linux-next` tree 6 days ago.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/commit/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek?h=next-20200720&id=0439297be95111cf9ef5ece2091af16d140ce2ef

It will take some time to get into `stable` and then into Ubuntu.

You can try to install drivers from the Realtek site before Linux supports it natively. You'll need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS and blacklist `r8169` to get them working.

The issue is fixed in the 5.9 kernel. Unfortunately Ubuntu 20.10 and 20.04.2 won't have this kernel. So a mainline kernel, or a backport is needed.

Comment: I did install the 5.8.0 kernel from mainline ubuntu but the card is still not working.

Comment: It hasn't been added to `5.8`. It should appear in 5.9.

Comment: I've installed realtek drivers and blacklisted the module, seems to work... for now.

Comment: This is a way of running. It would be useful if you write an answer about which drivers you installed and how.

Comment: It seems that the driver was added to 5.4.0-762. My LAN is now working on Pop!_OS

Comment: No, it hasn't been added.

Comment: then I have no idea why it's working for me now

Comment: After installing r8125, from time to time my PC automatically upgrades the driver to r8169, making internet inaccessible again, do you guys know how to disable this specific upgrade?

Comment: You understood this wrong. After a kernel upgrade the `r8125` should be rebuilt against the new kernel. To avoid this you need to install it using dkms.

Comment: Do you have any source of dkms install? I can't find on internet

Comment: @Negrito `dkms.conf` can be easily made.

Comment: yes kernel 5.9 fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Thanks guys.... worked for me by installing the 5.10 kernel.

Answer (score 31):

I had the same exact issue. Looks like you're missing drivers for the Ethernet.

Go to this link (which is from the actual Ethernet provider): https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software

Download the "2.5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125 for kernel up to 5.6" and follow the installation instructions.

You should be able to use wired connection once you're done.

Comment: I tried that (see the second comment under the main question), but until I had internet connection working on the computer, I couldn't install the necessary packages for the instalation/compilation... since the fresh install of Ubuntu does not come with even the build-essentials...

Comment: The above solution fixed my broken Ethernet LAN. Instructions are in the README file of the download from the link provided above by MrGoldWatch. I have a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04.1 on a new PC build with Gigabyte B550 Aorus Master with Realtek 8125B 2.5G Ethernet. Instructions are short and worked immediately, but I had to first install make using `sudo apt-get install build-essential` using a wifi connection.

Comment: This worked for me on a Proxmox 6.2-1 distribution running on an ASRock Z490M-ITX/ac motherboard.  Check the README file in the driver and run the autorun.sh script, then add the interface in /etc/network/interfaces.  For me the new interface name was `enp3s0`.

`Linux proxmox 5.4.65-1-pve #1 SMP PVE 5.4.65-1 (Mon, 21 Sep 2020 15:40:22 +0200) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Worked for me on an MSI Z490 motherboard. If you do not see the ethX as described in the README, try the good old reboot method. :)

Comment: same here on ubuntu 20.04. but ubuntu got upset At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory

Comment: Worked for me; this was all I needed... updated drivers.

Comment: FYI, you may have to re-install the driver at some point in the future (e.g. after a kernal upgrade).

Comment: The answers from Pilot6, MrGoldWatch and user2904033 have all worked for me on multiple builds of Ubuntu. Updated the 5.8 kernel to 5.10 on Ubuntu Server v20 worked and upgrading the realtek drivers on Ubuntu Desktop v20 (5.8 kernel) worked as well. I can't thank you guys enough. :)

Comment: This worked like a charm. Make sure you install `sudo apt-get install build-essential` before running the `.sh` file therein with `sudo` privileges.

Comment: just an update, this didn't work on Proxmox 6.4 with Kernel 5.4.174 with the 9.004 or 9.008 drivers.  using the kernel 5.11 without any additional driver installation worked.

After rebooting and using grub to select the 5.4.65 kernel I was then able to switch to the 5.11 kernel using the commands here:

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/kernel-5-11.86225/

Now my proxmox box is running `Linux 5.11.22-5-pve` just fine.

Answer (score 9):

There are no installation instructions on the realtek download page.

Anyways [this](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/realtek-rtl8125-2-5gbe-ethernet-not-working-on-amd-b550-mobo/22469/2) solution worked for me:

```
Here's a solution I found;

    Go to the Realtek website 387

    Download the Unix(Linux) r8125 driver. You will need to give an email address.
    1754×445

    Go to /Downloads directory. Extract the Tarball.

    In Terminal, go into r8125-xxxx folder and run the autorun.sh

    $ sudo ./autorun.sh

Everything should run automatically and you should get ethernet connection now.
```

Comment: I do not understand why they have not added support for network adapters for the Asus TUF 550 motherboard. This issue has happened to me a few times with this motherboard and Ubuntu 20.04 over various updates.

Comment: Worked for me under Debian 10 (MB is MSI MAG B460M MORTAR WIFI). No additional packages were required it seems.

Comment: Thank you very much @user2904033. It worked for me.

Comment: Might be worth noting that you need some dependencies to install at, at least make. In doubt I installed `build-essential`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried alot of solutions and this one worked for me! Worked on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens with me on kernel 5.4 now with kernel 5.10 there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Good news from year 2022**

This [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1916558) made it into [20.04.3](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/20.04.3#Kernel_and_Hardware_support_updates), so the network card works now out of the box :)

Comment: For Ubuntu Server installs you'll need to opt into the Hardware Enablement stack to get the updated kernel: https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle