# Ubuntu Server 20.04 no internet connection/network unclaimed

Tags: networking, server, 20.04

I tried installing Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my Gigabyte B550i with an Realtek Ethernet Controller and wireless. I want to use ethernet (I don't care about wireless), but I wasn't able to set it up during installation and `cat /etc/netplan.*yaml` returns just:

```
network:
      version 2
```

and `lshw -C network` lists both networks, the ethernet one unclaimed, the wireless one diabled. `/etc/network/interfaces` is empty, I tried different file contents, but nothing worked.

What am I doing wrong? I tried installing some kind of drivers, but didn't succeed.

**EDIT**

`ip a` returns

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqeue state UNKOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preffered_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope ost
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp6s0 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:cf:f6:b7:d4:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**EDIT 2 Images**

[lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VysUZ.jpg)

[lspci -k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ahKl.jpg)

Comment: Please add the output of `ip a`

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Your .yaml file is broken.

Comment: Please add the output of `rfkill list` and `lspci -k`

Comment: Please show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Newest one I think, it returns F1

Comment: Please see the Update #1 in my answer. Only do the BIOS update for now.

Comment: Did your $13 USB to Ethernet adapter arrive yet?

Comment: @heynnema yes it arrived, and it worked, but now I had to return my PSU, because it stopped working when I attached all drives. I'll write you as soon as I get to the installing of the driver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your netplan .yaml file is broken.

`ls -al /etc/netplan` # get .yaml filename

`sudo lshw -C network` # identify ethernet device name, enxxxxxx

Edit it with:

`sudo pico /etc/netplan/*.yaml` <-- change the * to your filename

Initially make its content the following, with EXACLY the same spacing, indentation, and no tabs:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    en01:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlp6s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      access-points:
        "YourWifiNetworkName":
          password: "WifiNetworkPassword"
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

**BIOS**

You have BIOS version F1.

The current BIOS is version F2a, dated 6/16/2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard model #.

Note: Have good backup before updating the BIOS.

**kernel**

With the newer ethernet controller that you have, you may need to run with a newer kernel than stock from Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Go [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8.3/) to download the latest 5.8.3 kernel. Get the 4 regular .deb files, **not** the lowlatency files.

**Update #2:**

Word is that not even kernel 5.8.3 supports the RTL8125! Kernel 5.9 is supposed to support it, but there is only a 5.9-rc2 (rc2 means release candidate #2) version available now... see [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9-rc2/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9-rc2/).

In the mean time, download this Linux driver from Realtek, and it should work. https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software. Get the one for "2.5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125 for kernel up to 5.6"... and use your original 5.4.x kernel.

**Update #3:**

Ordered a $13 `TP-Link USB 3.0 Ethernet dongle` to be able to connect and download/install required Ubuntu packages. [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00YUU3KC6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YUU3KC6)

**Update #4:**

Installed USB to Ethernet adapter. Installed `build-essential`. Built driver. Everything works. Wireless will be completed when the need arises. Will need to install `wpasupplicant`.

Comment: I'm not able to find the ethernet device name. I updated the original post with some images.

Comment: BIOS is updated now.

Comment: @hertelukas Does `sudo lshw -C network` now give us an ethernet device name? If not, do backups, then try the newer kernel.

Comment: no, output is the same

Comment: @hertelukas Do the newer 5.8.3 kernel. See if you find a device name with `sudo lshw -C network`, then edit the .yaml file, etc. Report back.

Comment: still the same. `uname -r` returns 5.8.3, but there is no name with `sudo lshw -C network`. (But I tried setting up the Wifi for now, so the second network is no longer DISABLED)

Comment: @hertelukas Just to eliminate a gross software issue, try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if `ip ` or `sudo lshw -C network` show the ethernet device name.

Comment: @hertelukas I may have found a Linux driver for the RTL8125 ethernet card at https://www.realtek.com/zh-tw/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software, get the one for "2.5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125 for kernel up to 5.6". Report back.

Comment: @hertelukas Ah! See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04

Comment: @hertelukas Here's the English download page... https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software

Comment: @hertelukas See Update #2 in my answer.

Comment: how can I update the driver? When trying to run the autorun.sh script with `chmod +x autorun.sh`  and `./autorun.sh` `Check old driver and unload it. Build the module and install ./autron.sh: 30: make: not found` returns

Comment: @hertelukas  `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install build-essential` should probably install the missing make command.

Comment: How should I do that without internet?

Comment: @hertelukas Ehh... you're right. How did you get the .deb files for 5.8.3? If you do Thomas Wards wireless answer, with my comments, you can get it that way.

Comment: I used a flash drive. But I never installed a package with a flash drive. (Furthermore, I'm back on the initial installation). For Thomas Solution I seem to need `wpasupplicant`, same issue I think? At the moment on startup, I allways get stuck for 2 minutes in `A start job is running for Wait for Network is Configured` and I'm still not connected (pretty sure I entered the netplan details correctly)

Comment: @hertelukas http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wpa/wpasupplicant_2.9-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb

Comment: @hertelukas For netplan, you can only put the wireless detail in the .yaml, not the ethernet stuff, as we don't have all of the info, or driver, yet.

Comment: it finally worked! Thank you so much. (Just one HDD is broken, so I still have to wait to use my NAS)

Comment: @hertelukas Great news! Thanks for the update. What enxxxxxx device did the primary RTL8125 ethernet device show up as? I want to edit my answer with that detail. And the new driver worked? And you're running kernel 5.4.x? And wpasupplicant for the wireless?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Kernel 5.4.0. Furthermore, the device name is `eno1`. The driver is working, just ran autorun.sh (and I had to `sudo apt-get install build-essential`). I didn't try wpasupplicant, because I don't need wireless at the moment. If I decide to use it, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try configuring this for Wifi but it'll require you to do some more work.

Your wifi device is: `wlp6s0`

Try this netplan configuration in place of whatever you currently have (AND MAKE SURE YOU MATCH SPACING!), then run `sudo netplan test` and reboot the server after:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp6s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      access-points:
        "YourWifiNetworkName":
          password: "WifiNetworkPassword"
```

Replace `YourWifiNetworkName` and `WifiNetworkPassword` accordingly to manually set the wifi network and its connection authentication password that your server will connect to.  **You do need the quotes around those two arguments, as shown in the [Netplan Examples and the exact example I referenced](https://netplan.io/examples/#connecting-to-a-wpa-personal-wireless-network).**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112277/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-ward-ubuntu-server-20-04-no-internet-connection-n).

Comment: Remember to change `test` to `try`, and you also need to install `wpasupplicant`. I still think the sequence should be generate/apply, or generate/try/apply.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by pulling out my bios/uefi battery for several minutes and it worked like a charm! It happened twice and I solved it twice this way. I did everything listed here and more but it didn't solved my problem. I didn't touch bios/uefi settings before. This is not a joke. I got the same problem with intel network adapter on Ubuntu 20.04. Terminal `lshw` listed my adapter as `UNCLAIMED`. I tried every page with the same problem but it didn't solved this issue.