# Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 can't connect to ethernet or wifi

Tags: dual-boot, ethernet

I had been using wsl2 on the Windows Insider preview for a while, but was getting fed up with programs I needed to work breaking due to it being a dev build. As a result I decided to switch to a dual boot system so I could use a stable Windows version for the programs I need which are Windows exclusive and Ubuntu for my other requirements.

After getting Ubuntu installed, I am unable to connect to ethernet or Wi-Fi. After running `sudo lshw -C network` and `ls /sys/class/net` I get the following results(typed due to inability to post imgs, formatting may be weird as a result):

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
     
     description: Ethernet controller
     product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
     version: 05
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc510000-fc513fff
```

`lo`

In case it's relevant, while setting up the installation I only explicitly set the / and /home partitions as recommended by the guide I was following.

Given I have no way of updating or upgrading the system due to the lack of connection I'm totally lost as to how to proceed.

Comment: Have you seen [the solution over here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1270058/1091774)? Looks like the person asking the question has the exact same network card and the exact same problem 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cant get RTL8125 Realtek driver working on version 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287967/cant-get-rtl8125-realtek-driver-working-on-version-20-04). Looks like your installation choices were  irrelevant -- you have unfortunate hardware. Consider going back to WSL (or other Virtualization), or purchasing a Linux-compatible network dongle until your next hardware change.

Comment: Unfortunately, that first solution didn't work. However, I have purchased a new dongle which should be compatible. It's just unfortunate that my pre-existing one wasn't compatible.