# Ubuntu 20.10 no internet connection / network unclaimed

Tags: networking, 20.04, system-installation, realtek, 20.10

I have installed Ubuntu 20.10 on a dedicated SSD on my computer (Windows 10 is installed on another drive).
But my network card (only ethernet, no wifi) is not detected and I cannot access internet.
I have a Gigabyte B550 Aorus Pro which integrates a Realtek RTL8125 2.5Gb network card.
The closest topic I could find is this [Question for similar problem on Ubuntu server 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270046/ubuntu-server-20-04-no-internet-connection-network-unclaimed), i tried the proposed solutions but to no avail.

I have also tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with same results.

Is there something that I can do, or due to my "too recent" network card I can forget about Ubuntu supporting it?

Results of `cat /etc/netplan.*yaml` :

[image: cat /etc/netplan.*yaml]

interfaces do not exist in `/etc/network`

[image: interfaces do not exist in /etc/network]

Results of `lshw -C network` :

[image: lshw -C network]

Results of `ip a` :

[image: ip a]

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I'd order a simple ($15 or so) dedicated network card to bridge the time until your on-board network adapter is properly supported by the kernel.

Comment: or USB ethernet adapter

Comment: How can I make sure an USB ethernet adapter will be well recognised by Ubuntu (being offline)? Thanks

Comment: You can't be absolutely sure, of course, but most of those simple USB devices use older chipsets that tend to be well-supported. If you are lucky, one of the reviewers on the shop website already wrote that it works with Linux.