# Ubuntu 20.4 Desktop Wired network unclaimed/Setting Missing

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

New to Ubuntu, linux (as in my first install was 3 days ago). Had it working on a wired connection initially, but then installed a few system updates, and then my wired settings were gone. I've scoured this site and a few more looking at very similar problems, but given the unique nature of each machine, I didn't feel comfortable moving forward with any particular option without getting some more expert opinions. Now my ethernet is network UNCLAIMED.  I've got lshw -C network, ip a, and lspci -k readouts, but please let me know if I need more.

EDIT 1

**lspci -k**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 4-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 4-port SATA Controller [IDE mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 2-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 2-port SATA Controller [IDE mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 660] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GK106 [GeForce GTX 660]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GK106 HDMI Audio Controller
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
```

**alex@Bread:~$ lspci -nn**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0150] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1e18] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation H77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e4a] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 4-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:1e00] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
00:1f.5 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 2-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:1e08] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 660] [10de:11c0] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e0b] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 09)
```

**alex@Bread:~$ lspci -nn | grep -i ethernet**

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 09)
```

EDIT 2

```
    alex@Bread:~$ dkms status
nvidia, 460.39, 5.8.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.39, 5.8.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

```
alex@Bread:~$ sudo lshw -c network
```

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 09
       serial: 60:a4:4c:b5:1c:a9
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168f-1_0.0.5 06/18/12 ip=192.168.10.152 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2104000-f2104fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff}
```

sudo modprobe r8168 resulted in the connection being restored and now the wired connection settings have returned. As a note, your assistance is greatly appreciated.

EDIT 3

dkms status

```
nvidia, 460.39, 5.8.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 460.39, 5.8.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
```

sudo modprobe r8169
Reboot
sudo lshw -c network

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 09
       serial: 60:a4:4c:b5:1c:a9
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168f-1_0.0.5 06/18/12 ip=192.168.10.152 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2104000-f2104fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

Internet working and settings restored after modprobe r8168, modprobe r8169 had no readily apparent effect.

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms

```
total 1620
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Mar 31 11:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Mar 31 11:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1648704 Mar 31 11:25 nvidia-uvm.ko
```

grep -i r816 /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf

returns nothing, just moves to the next command line.

Comment: Check this trend https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270046/ubuntu-server-20-04-no-internet-connection-network-unclaimed

Comment: Best to copy/paste text output into your answer, rather than a screenshot. Your lspci output is incomplete. Edit your question and show me `lspci -nn | grep -i ethernet` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Show me `dkms status` (as an edit to your question, not in the comments please). Then do `sudo modprobe r8169`, tell me the result, then show me `sudo lshw -c network`. You also didn't show me the output of all of the commands that I requested.

Comment: @heynnema  edits made as directed

Comment: Alex... you still haven't done what I asked. I'd like to put together an answer for you, but until I get all of the data that I need, I can't. Please pay closer attention. You haven't shown me `cat /etc/network/interfaces`, and I asked for `sudo modprobe r8169` but you did r8168. REBOOT first, then the correct modprobe command, and then redo the lshw command. Also show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Your `dkms status` shows a problem with your Nvidia driver.

Comment: Also show me `ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms`.

Comment: Also show me `grep -i r816 /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf`.

Comment: @heynnema My apologies about missing the details on your instructions, I've corrected that. It seems like the wired settings are back and functional, and that my nvidia is operating correctly, given that I've played a few games smoothly. Should I be concerned about anything else?

Comment: @Alex Reboot the computer and see if the ethernet is still working. It may not be. Also, `dkms status` shows an Nvidia driver problem... so you may wish to `sudo apt purge` the driver (or `sudo dkms remove` it) and reinstall it.

Comment: @heynnema I've rebooted several times over the last day, and it's still functional. I'll reinstall the nvidia driver though, and get that corrected. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Alex Good! I don't know what fixed it though, so I can't put together an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you had r8168 installed, and r8169 is blacklisted. After a kernel update r8168 is gone. So no driver is left, therefore NIC is unclaimed. Just remove the r8169 blacklisting.
This seems to be a frequent issue and should be covered by some FAQ.