# Installing Ubuntu 20.04.1 (or 18.04) on Asus TUF B550M-Plus motherboard

Tags: drivers, kernel, asus

I am trying to install and setup Ubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 20.04.1 on my PC with:
motherboard: Asus TUF B550m-Plus
Processor: Ryzen 5 3600
Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic

The problem is that I do not get my network card (RTL8125) recognized therefore I cannot install any drivers using apt-get. To make problem worse build-essentials were not installed during the ubuntu installation therefore I cannot use MAKE to install RTL8125 driver. I also tried to install new kernels (5.7,5.8 and 5.9) by downloading 4 .deb files representing headers,image and modules but it fails after unpacking linux-modules with error "unexpected end of file" (I tried downloading it again and the same happened).

I am stuck in vicious circle where I am always missing something to make this work. Can someone please help me and suggest what Ubuntu version should I install?

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04

Comment: cannot install driver because Make or gcc is not installed. Entire build-essentials failed to install and I cannot install them

Comment: Since you haven't gotten things set up yet, I suggest that you start over.  Unless you know for a fact that a new kernel will solve your issue, I would strongly discourage you from messing with it.  In general, if you're new to linux, you shouldn't mess around with `.deb` packages.  You will just spawn new problems.   Use `apt` or the software center for your package management.  Your issue is probably hardware specific to your wifi adapter and you should look at Q&As about your specific make/model adapter.