# Need help changing Ethernet driver

Tags: drivers, ethernet, realtek

I have a driver issue with my ethernet, it seems the wrong driver is loaded.  It's a realtek 8125, but the drivers loaded are for r8169.  I did recently install the drivers from their website, but also had a kernel update to version 5.9-.  The funny thing is the ethernet works, but peaks at 12mpbs (opposed to 75mpbs).

What would the best way of getting the correct driver installed without screwing up my system?  This is my 5th install of Ubuntu in 2020, but I'm starting to get the hang of it.

````
System:    Host: plunder-MS-7C76 Kernel: 5.9.0-8.2-liquorix-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop System: Micro-Star product: MS-7C76 v: 1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Micro-Star model: MPG Z490M GAMING EDGE WIFI (MS-7C76) v: 1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           BIOS: American Megatrends v: 2.20 date: 07/23/2020 
CPU:       6-Core: Intel Core i5-10600K type: MT MCP speed: 4109 MHz min/max: 800/4901 MHz 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER] driver: nvidia v: 450.80.02 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: nvidia resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.80.02 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE driver: r8169 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 2.03 TiB used: 517.93 GiB (24.9%) 
Info:      Processes: 423 Uptime: 15h 48m Memory: 31.29 GiB used: 9.52 GiB (30.4%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38```
````

Comment: Ubuntu installed the wrong driver from the gate.  It's a known issue on Ubuntu with the r8125.  From what I learned, the problem was fixed in the 5.9 kernel.

Comment: It doesn't work by default on Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04

Comment: I'm thinking if someone can help me figure out how to blacklist the r8169, it might work.

Comment: @TheTrumanShow Create `/etc/modprobe.d/r8169-blacklist.conf` and put "blacklist r8169" in (without the quotes).

Comment: I tried the command above and the driver still reads r8169.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  I had to reinstall the Realtek drivers after I updated my kernel.  So it seems when I updated my kernel from 5.8 to 5.9, I had to reinstall the drivers again.  Not sure what caused it, but it fixed it. Thanks for the help!

```
System:
  Host: plunder-MS-7C76 Kernel: 5.9.0-8.2-liquorix-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Micro-Star product: MS-7C76 v: 1.0 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: Micro-Star model: MPG Z490M GAMING EDGE WIFI (MS-7C76) v: 1.0 
  serial: <superuser/root required> BIOS: American Megatrends v: 2.20 
  date: 07/23/2020 
CPU:
  6-Core: Intel Core i5-10600K type: MT MCP speed: 4110 MHz 
  min/max: 800/4901 MHz 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER] driver: nvidia 
  v: 450.80.02 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: nvidia 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2 
  v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.80.02 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE driver: r8125 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 2.03 TiB used: 517.78 GiB (24.9%) 
Info:
  Processes: 384 Uptime: N/A Memory: 31.29 GiB used: 1.31 GiB (4.2%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```