# Wired Setting Missing and Ethernet Connection Not Working on Dual Boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10

Tags: networking, 20.04, windows-10, ethernet, realtek

I recently built a new pc and dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on them. My ethernet connection works in Windows 10 but does not work in Ubuntu. In addition, my the wired setting is missing in my network settings in Ubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I cannot seem to figure out what to do as I am new to Ubuntu/linux and have gotten lost.

I have tried to download the realtek drivers onto a usb but was unable to download them because ubuntu could not use make. I have also changed the power energy settings in Windows 10 but that did not help either. I am unsure how to proceed, I have seen people commonly provide the outputs below and I hope they help.

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Ethernet controller
product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
version: 05
width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc300000-fc30ffff memory:fc310000-fc313fff


*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
logical name: wlp9s0
version: 10
serial: f8:ac:65:a3:2f:64
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  resources: irq:91 memory:fc200000-fc201fff
```

Here is the output of `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp9s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 
1000
link/ether f8:ac:65:a3:2f:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `uname -r` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get RTL8125B working on 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04)

Comment: Connect to the internet using your phone to download build-essential, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up fixing the problem by downloading the Realtek rtl8125 drivers from another computer and transferring to my pc via usb flash drive. After following the readme instructions in that file and running the download script the wired ethernet connection began working.