# Wired network settings missing in Ubuntu Desktop 20.10

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, wired

This seems to be a longstanding bug that has appeared in many releases.
A fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 does not show the Wired Network Settings.
I only have Wireless internet access. Turning this off results in no internet.
The ethernet cable is working, since Windows on the same PC running on it. The ethernet LED lights are also indicating a connection and on Manjaro - which I had installed previously - had an ethernet connection.
Therefore I suspect the problem to reside in Ubuntu software.

No wired network settings:

[image: No wired network settings]

Running the following line results in the following output:

```
sudo lshw -c net
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Does anyone know how to let the wired network setting appear, and enable ethernet?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`? This may offer a little more insight into the network device 

Comment: @Matigo 

lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3 gives:

26:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 04)
 Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1462:7c84]
 Kernel modules: r8169
28:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)

Comment: It seems to be the same ethernet controller and module as mentioned by @chili555.
I will have a good look at this reference.

Comment: Indeed. If you need a step-by-step, post back and I'll assist.

Comment: I made some progress.

I downloaded the Realtek driver from [here](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software).
Installed the build essentials with 'sudo apt-get install build-essential', and then ran the autorun.sh as sudo.

This succeeded and now I have the 'Wired' section in the Network Settings. It also appears in the top right, under the quick settings.
However, its constantly 'Connecting'. I don't have internet access through the wired connection yet.
Will investigate.

Comment: The ouput from autorun.sh:

Check old driver and unload it.
Build the module and install
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
DEPMOD 5.8.0-41-generic
load module r8125
Updating initramfs. Please wait.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-41-generic
Completed.

Comment: Initially the connection was not active. After a reboot it did, and now I have a working ethernet connection.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get RTL8125B working on 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the references posted by @chili555 these steps enabled wired connections in my case:

1. Install build-essential: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
2. Download the  [driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software).
3. Run the autorun script as root.
4. Reboot.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem and for me the issue was in my netplan yaml file. I had to change the "renderer" to NetworkManager in the netplan file. You may need to add or change the renderer line as follows, and then "sudo netplan apply".

```sh
cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

```yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
```

Also, worth mentioning that `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` file should have access rights/mode where `others` cannot read the file. So, you may want to:

```sh
chmod 600 /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

Comment: This worked for me when I migrated from ifupdown to Netplan. Forgot the renderers where different for each platform.

Comment: this worked, though the config excerpt needs to be formatted to insert line feeds;

`network:<lf>
version: 2<lf>
renderer: NetworkManager<lf>
ethernets:<lf>`

Comment: This worked for me. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 Server initially and then installed the Desktop environment. Ubuntu Server uses `netplan` as the renderer so it was not updated to `NetworkManager` when I installed the Desktop environment.

Comment: This solved my problem on 22.04 with the wired ethernet not displaying in Settings for a Lenovo M93p mini/tiny pc.  There were no driver problems etc. - the issue was setting the renderer.

Answer (score 1):

This means there is no driver attached to your Ethernet Network Card. This can be solved by installing linux-backports.

Your problem has a solution [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1314693#:%7E:text=%27Unclaimed%27%20typically%20means%20no%20driver,Code%3A%20%5BView%5D).

Success!

Comment: Hi, @Justech, which part of the link is the actual solution? Can you please edit your answer to include it? I tried searching for linux-backports by running `apt-cache search "linux-backports"` but got no results

Answer (score 1):

Since none of these solutions worked for me I wanted to share what did.

I had modified the file /etc/network/interfaces

I had added code to make my connection DHCP and it appears to have caused this issue we all share here.

I removed everything from that file except for what was originally in there and rebooted my PC. Then magically my settings were all back to normal.

Hope it helps someone.

Cheers.