GUI not showing wired ethernet network connection?
My wired connection works OK, but - I don't see anything related to this wired ethernet network connection under Settings/Network? It's Ubuntu 22.04.

The wired connection works OK since long, it's just that nothing is in the GUI.

Yes, my GUI does show something on that screen. Take a look at the answers at the following question for some possible solutions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312096/wired-network-settings-missing-in-ubuntu-desktop-20-10
