# Ethernet Cable Not Being Recognized

Tags: drivers, 20.04, internet, ethernet

Brand new to Ubuntu, got it installed today. It does not recognize my ethernet cable. I am trying to install the drivers from realtek, but having a really hard time. All kinds of errors and searching all the responses, they seem to need commands that I do not have an cannot update. Any help much appreciated, this is very frustrating.

I'm using 20.04 LTS

```
sudo lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b53 (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bc5 (rev 05)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d2
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b8 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06bc (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0685
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 04)
```

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1100000-b110ffff memory:b1110000-b1113fff
```

Comment: Could you update your question to include the output of `lspci` and `lshw -C network`? This will show specific information about your hardware, making more likely someone can offer an answer 

Comment: Thanks, added outputs of the requested commands

Answer (score 1):

As an introduction to Ubuntu, this is going to seem rather involved. A lot of installations are straightforward and simple. Sometimes there are situations where a little more work is required.

At the moment you have three options:

1. Wait for the 21.04 release of Ubuntu, which will include support for your network adapter. This is expected in April.
2. Install the 5.10 Linux kernel, which supports your adapter, using [a walk-through like this](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-linux-kernel-5-10-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/)
3. Compile [the driver from Realtek](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software), so long as you are using the 5.4 kernel. If you’re on 5.8, this may not work.

As this is your first foray with Ubuntu, it may make sense to go with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've could searched in this [forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04).

Looks like you'll have wait until the changes/update will reach you.

If you ask why:

Realtek has just provided a [driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/directly-download?downloadid=95f1076134d28cfcebcb49fc65a6811e), (2021/02/01) but it needs to be "packaged" for Ubuntu/Debian - which takes some time