# I Update Ubuntu 20.04 And It Knocked Out My Ethernet And Wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

This is really frustrating.

Every update knocks out my connection. Luckily I kept a download of my ethernet driver in my Downloads folder and was able to reinstall it in seconds. But it would be nice if there was some way to stop updates from doing this? Or if updates would just stop killing my network drivers.

This is the thread I am using to solve this problem in the mean time.

[Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04/1319868#1319868)

Comment: As this is a question and answer site you seemed to have answered your own question. At the bottom of the question there is a box answer you own question. would be best to put that solution in there.

Comment: What you seem to be saying is that you must reinstall your kernel module (driver) after every kernel update because your vendor (Realtek) provides shoddy Linux support for that model of hardware. That does not seem an Ubuntu issue. That seems a Realtek issue, They could provide the support that you expected when you paid them for Linux-compatible hardware. Other hardware manufacturers do.