# Ethernet not loaded

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04.2 and wifi is working normally but ethernet is not loaded at all. Like a driver is missing... This is what I get from  `lshw -C network`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
    description: Ethernet controller
    product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
    version: 04
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc700000-fc70ffff memory:fc710000-fc713fff
*-network
    description: Wireless interface
    product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:28:00.0
    logical name: wlo1
    version: 1a
    serial: ac:12:03:d8:79:80
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode ip=192.168.1.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
    resources: irq:37 memory:fc600000-fc603fff
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get RTL8125B working on 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04)  However, Realtek themselves have the driver at https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software but I don't have this card in my system so I can't install it and give you step by step.

Comment: Hell yeah, made it work. Thanks bro