# r8125 PCIe card not working with 20.04.2 / kernel 5.9 / Gigabyte B550M-DS3H

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, realtek, lan

I am attempting to upgrade my home network to 2.5 Gbps ethernet using r8125 PCIe cards ([Cudy](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B08L8PK1SF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)). After considerable troubleshooting effort and research, I am unable to get this working on this machine. Despite the card being recognized (`enp6s0`), it does not pass any data (no internet or LAN connection).

Secure boot is off:

```
$ mokutil --sb-state

EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

System info:

```
$ inxi -F

    System:    Host: zephyr Kernel: 5.9.0-050900-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: LXQt 0.14.1 

Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: Gigabyte model: B550M DS3H v: x.x serial:  

BIOS: American Megatrends v: F10 date: 09/18/2020 

CPU:       Topology: 8-Core model: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
           Speed: 2196 MHz min/max: 2200/3600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2195 2: 2195 3: 2189 4: 2191 5: 2196 6: 2196 7: 2189 8: 2195 9: 2196 10: 2193 11: 2197 12: 2196 13: 2194 14: 2192 15: 2195 16: 2190 

Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430] driver: radeon v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: radeon FAILED: ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD CEDAR (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.9.0-050900-generic LLVM 11.0.0) v: 3.3 Mesa 20.2.6 

Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300/7300 Series] driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.9.0-050900-generic 

Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE driver: r8169 
           IF: enp6s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: b4:4b:d6:27:23:06 
           

Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
           IF: enp9s0 state: down mac: 18:c0:4d:6e:99:ff** 

Drives:    
Local Storage: total: 14.67 TiB used: 156.59 GiB (1.0%) 

ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Transcend model: TS128GMTE110S size: 119.24 GiB 

ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD40EZRZ-22GXCB0 size: 3.64 TiB 

ID-3: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD40EZRZ-19GXCB0 size: 3.64 TiB 

ID-4: /dev/sdg vendor: Western Digital model: 
WD40EZRZ-22GXCB0 size: 3.64 TiB 

ID-5: /dev/sdh vendor: Western Digital model: WD40EZRZ-22GXCB0 size: 3.64 TiB 

RAID:
Device-1: md0 type: mdraid status: active raid: raid-10 report: 4/4 UUUU Components:  online: sdb~c1 sdg~c2 sda~c0 sdh~c3 

Partition: ID-1: / size: 116.87 GiB used: 30.55 GiB (26.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 

Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 76.9 C mobo: N/A gpu: radeon temp: 16 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 

Info:      Processes: 417 Uptime: 28m Memory: 15.62 GiB used: 2.56 GiB (16.4%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38 


$ lspci | grep Realtek
    
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)

$ lsmod | grep r8125
r8125                 159744  0


$ lsmod | grep r8169
r8169                  94208  0

$ ethtool enp6s0
Settings for enp6s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
                                2500baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
                                2500baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Link detected: no
```

[edit]

```
$ cd r8125
$ sudo ./autorun.sh
[sudo] password for kevin: 

Check old driver and unload it.
rmmod r8125
Build the module and install
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
DEPMOD 5.9.0-050900-generic
load module r8125
Updating initramfs. Please wait.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.9.0-050900-generic
Completed.
```

Steps I have tried:

- installed r8125 drivers (v. 9.005.01) from Realtek website
- performed dkms install as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263363/2-5g-ethernet-linux-driver-r8125-installation-guide)
- disabled onboard LAN port in UEFI (Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169)
- unloaded r8169 driver with `sudo modprobe -r r8169`
- activated card by `sudo ifconfig enp6s0 up`
- Loaded Linux kernel 5.9 which has native r8125 support
- blacklisted r8169 in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf [edit]
- swapped with identical model NIC known to work in another system [edit]
- moved NIC to a different PCIe slot [edit]

Other observations:

- I have another system with Gigabyte B450M-D3SH with the same Cudy card installed which passes data successfully.  I have not swapped this card in yet to test for a defective unit.
- It is curious that the onboard LAN seems to be recognized as a PCIe device: `Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169`.  Could this relate to the source of the problem somehow?

I am at a loss as to the cause of this problem.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The driver can be found at https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software for the r8125 that works with 20.04.  Someone I gave this hint to was able to install it at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330909/ethernet-not-loaded#comment2269221_1330909  I wish I had the card in my system so I could do a step by step install for a good answer.

Comment: You may have to blacklist the r8169 driver, as it's running the card now (instead of the Realtek driver). *Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE driver: r8169*.

Comment: @hennema: I forgot to include that I also tried blacklisting r8169, but that didn't work either.  I have added it to the list above.

Comment: @Terrance:  If you are referring to "2.5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125 for kernel up to 5.6" that is the one I have downloaded and installed, and is the same as at the end of the link trail you provided.  I see another under the rubric of "Others" called "RTL8125B Ring Library driver"... haven't tried this as it's not clearly marked for Linux, and I'm not sure what it's for.  Thanks.

Comment: The only one that should work would be the one for Linux.  I believe the Ring Library would be for Ring topology networks, but I am not 100% sure. Try doing a hard power cycle on your system by unplugging the power from it and pressing the power button a few times then power it back up.  Have you tried another cable that you know works to see if it is getting any IPs?

Comment: @Terrance:  the cable is ok; I can switch back to the onboard LAN port with the same cable and LAN access is restored. I cycled the power as you described, with negative results.  I swapped the duplicate NICs, resulting in the same behavior in each machine (therefore, its not a defective NIC). I repeated the procedure of disabling onboard LAN in UEFI, removing r8169 and manually installing r8125, with negative results.  I do note, however, there is a persistent SSL signing error for r8125 on this machine that was remedied by the dkms procedure on the machine in which the NIC works.

Comment: @Terrance: Another observation is that when booting with LAN cable in the non-functioning NIC, it hangs for approximately 90 sec attempting to scan the network... as if r8125 drivers are not being loaded in the boot sequence.  This doesn't happen with the cable plugged into the functioning onboard LAN port.  I'm still stymied, but thanks for the helpful suggestions.

Comment: On the one that is not working, what is the output of `dkms status`?

Comment: $ dkms status
r8125, 9.005.01, 5.9.0-050900-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)

Comment: There is a way to fix that.  `sudo dkms uninstall -m r8125 -v 9.005.01 -k 5.9.0-050900-generic && sudo dkms install -m r8125 -v 9.005.01 -k 5.9.0-050900-generic --force`

Comment: $ dkms status
r8125, 9.005.01, 5.9.0-050900-generic, x86_64: installed
- SSL error persists  - r8125 NIC still non-functional.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using the 5.9 kernel?  I am just wondering as the HWE kernel version for 20.04 is 5.8.  Where are you getting this SSL error?  Can you add that to your quesiton?  Also, I have seen this before, but look in the socket on the card and see if there are any bent pins.  Mainly because the ethtool was saying no link.  I, honestly am running out of ideas for you.

Comment: b/c its my understanding that 5.9 contains r8125 drivers.  - SSL error added above; PCIe socket inspected --> nothing amiss; rearranged some hardware and rolled back to prior kernel (5.4) --> no change.   :-(  [edit] ethtool now shows "Link detected: yes"  but still no data exchange.

Comment: I am sorry, but the socket where the network cable plugs into it.  My bad.  Look for any physical damage in there.  I would now also suggest swapping the cards for the time being from the other system just to eliminate the hardware as being the issue.

Comment: Thank you.  I swapped out the cards and have ruled out a NIC hardware issue.

Comment: Moved NIC to a different PCIe slot: no change.  I am out of ideas, other than inviting motherboard manufacturer to review this comment string and offer any suggestions.

Comment: Solved.  It was an issue with no IP address being assigned to the new card.  After manually adding a static IP in /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml, I am basking in ~2.4 Gbps glory.  Suffice it to say that I need to learn much more about networking.  Thank you very much for your efforts.  Ref: LinuxTechi, "How to Assign Static IP Address on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS".

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post an answer describing how you solved it instead of editing the question

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. For safety, save a copy of `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` as `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml-old`. So you can revert if needed.
2. Modify `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` to read as follows:

   ```yaml
   network:
     ethernets:
       enp9s0:
         dhcp4: true
       enp4s0:
         addresses: [192.168.1.XX/24]
         gateway4: 192.168.1.1
         nameservers:
           addresses: [Y.Y.Y.Y, Z.Z.Z.Z]
     version: 2
   ```

   where X = desired LAN IP, Y & Z = DNS nameservers of choice, and using your adapter name (e.g., `enp4s0`). Be mindful that .yaml files are sensitive to indentation.
3. Save file
4. `sudo netplan apply`

I manually added from `enp4s0` thru `addresses`. While the above steps brought the NIC to life, the proper driver is still not loading at boot.  As this is a different problem, if unable to resolve I will post as a new thread.

https://www.linuxtechi.com/assign-static-ip-address-ubuntu-20-04-lts/