# RTL8125B NIC stopped working

Tags: drivers, realtek, dkms, nic

I have a 2.5GBps NIC: **RTL8125B** which did not work out-of-box. It would not even show up in `lspci`.

After installing [r8168-dkms](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/r8168-dkms) package, and rebooting, I was able to use it for a week or so.

Today, the NIC stopped working. The kernel sees no device, and `lspci` doesn't see it either.

I purged the r8168-dkms package, reinstalled it, and rebooted, which did not work.

I have a second machine with the same NIC, running the same Ubuntu version, and same r8168-dkms package.

That machine still sees the NIC, but it uses the **r8169** driver to do so.

I am also surprised that lspci will not list the device. Does lspci rely on drivers for that?

The lshw tool does not see it either as `lshw -C network` will only show my Intel NICs.

**OS:** Ubuntu 21.04

**Kernel:** 5.11.0-17-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP

**r8168-dkms:** 8.048.03-3

*UPDATE:*

Rebooting did not help, but an actual power-off by physically switching off the PSU, did help.

The system is a Xeon on a Supermicro X11-SRM-F server board, using IPMI, so maybe a reboot is not always a full reboot? It is unclear to me why a physical switching off resets more than a reboot?

After manual powercycle, I get:

```
65:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40, NUMA node 0
        I/O ports at b000 [size=256]
        Memory at e0e10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Memory at e0e20000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Expansion ROM at e0e00000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=32 Masked-
        Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 01-50-00-00-b0-b3-c9-88
        Capabilities: [178] Transaction Processing Hints
        Capabilities: [204] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [20c] L1 PM Substates
        Capabilities: [21c] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0002 Rev=4 Len=100 <?>
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

*UPDATE*

```
$ sudo modprobe r8125 && sudo dmesg | grep r81
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8125 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic
```

Comment: What about installing driver from realtek page? Like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04)

Comment: From that page: "The issue is fixed in the 5.9 kernel" and I am on the 5.11 kernel.

Comment: Yes, but it's worth trying.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8125 && sudo dmesg | grep r81`

Comment: "I am also surprised that lspci will not list the device. Does lspci rely on drivers for that?" No; if a device hasn't a working driver, it *still* shows in `lspci` but is marked UNCLAIMED. All PCI devices attached to the PCI bus should appear. This strange behavior suggests a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen PCI devices disapperaing on reboot on other systems. Try kernel parameter reboot=pci.
And by the way: r8168 can't be used for RTL8125. Realtek provides r8125 for this chip version. But this shouldn't be needed 5.9 as r8169 takes care.