# Can't connect to internet with ethernet or wifi on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: internet, ethernet

I'm very new to the Linux desktop world so apologies if this is a basic question.

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a partition in my PC. Windows can access the internet through ethernet or Wi Fi, no problems.

On Ubuntu, I cannot connect to the internet and don't know how to proceed.

The `01-network-manager-all.yaml` file shows

network:

version: 2

renderer: NetworkManager

Command `sudo lshw -C network` output:

*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Ethernet controller
product: RTL8125 2.5 GbE Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
version: 04
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc700000-fc70ffff memory: fc710000-fc713fff

`ip a` output:

1: lo: <LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000

link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

`lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` output:

26:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8125 2.5 GbE Controller [1462:7c84]
Kernel modules: r8169

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Most advice I see post online has to do with using the internet as a solution which isn't possible since I cannot connect at all.

Comment: There should be a great deal more to the `lshw` output. Can you [edit] your question to include the full output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `lspci`? This may make it easier to receive some specific advice on how to resolve the issue 

Comment: Edited to include the full output. Sorry it's a bit tedious because I'm typing it out by hand, lol.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.