# Ubuntu server 20.04 not showing ethernet in setup

Tags: server, 20.04

I'm setting up ubuntu server 20.04 on a new pc and I've got an ethernet cable directly in, but during setup it doesn't show ethernet in the "Network connections" setup section, and instead only shows the option to create a bond.

Comment: chances are that you have some hardware Linux doesn't know oob. Or your cable might not fit correctly. Could you paste the result of `lspci -v` into your question?

Comment: @kanehekili I can't paste it here since I'm on a different machine but it does contain "Ethernet container: realtek semiconductor co., LTD, RTL0125"

Comment: Isn't it RTL8125? There's no RTL0125

Comment: Yeah, misread it sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have problems with the REALTEK 8125 (which I assume from your comments) you can search [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259947/cant-get-rtl8125b-working-on-20-04) for more infos.

You might download it from their [site](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software)

Select the driver  `2.5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125 for kernel up to 5.6` and download it. It needs to be build with **make**

Note that this driver only works up to Kernel 5.6 (with 5.4 the mainstream kernel it should be ok).

Comment: "The product link is empty, please find the product from the page in the download centre and click Download icon to download it normally", it shows that text but in Chinese. I found it at this link: https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software

Comment: good, you're on the right track, I just saw the link, not investigated it.

Comment: I found that you need to compile it, is there a precompiled binary somewhere? I can't run make or download it, since no internet..

Comment: Not that I know of. But I could download the tar.bz from the link I mentioned. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Another way I resolved this is to simply use 21.10 or above. This came with the needed drivers and worked out of the box!