# How to install Ethernet driver on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

This recent post is nearly identical to my current issue: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402709/how-to-install-ethernet-driver-on-ubuntu-server-20-04-4-lts)

This is my first time using Linux and the first time setting up a server. I followed the online tutorial instructions to install on a fresh build of Ubuntu Desktop (so I have a GUI since I am new to it all).

The motherboard I am using is a Supermicro X11SPI-TF XEON MAX-1TB DDR4 ATX and Ubuntu does not recognize my Ethernet that is plugged in.

I am not sure how to install the ethernet drivers I suspect that I need. I attempted the same solution as shown in the link referenced but since I got different results that I do not know how to interpret, I assume the solution is different as well. I have attached the text file that has my results from the requests made in the other similar post made a few days ago.

- lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
- cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
- sudo dmesg | grep r816
- uname -r
- ip a

```
sprout@tol:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
sprout@tol:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
sprout@tol:~$ sudo dmesg | grep r816
sprout@tol:~$ uname -r
5.13.0-30-generic
sprout@tol:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

EDIT 1

- sudo lspci
- sudo lshw -c network

```
sprout@tol:~$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DMI3 Registers (rev 07)
00:04.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 07)
00:04.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 07)
00:04.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 07)
00:04.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 07)
00:04.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 07)
00:04.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 07)
00:04.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 07)
00:04.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers (rev 07)
00:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E MM/Vt-d Configuration Registers (rev 07)
00:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS (rev 07)
00:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E IOAPIC (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers (rev 07)
00:08.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers (rev 07)
00:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers (rev 07)
00:11.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family MROM 0 (rev 09)
00:11.1 Unassigned class [ff00]: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family MROM 1 (rev 09)
00:11.5 SATA controller: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family SSATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 09)
00:16.1 Communication controller: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #2 (rev 09)
00:16.4 Communication controller: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #3 (rev 09)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 09)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f9)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f9)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f9)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C622 Series Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 09)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 09)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 09)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation C620 Series Chipset Family SPI Controller (rev 09)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev 04)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation E12 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
16:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E VT-d (rev 07)
16:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers (rev 07)
16:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E IOxAPIC Configuration Registers (rev 07)
16:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:08.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:08.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:08.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:08.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:08.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:08.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:08.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:09.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:0e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:0e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:0e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:0e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:0e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:0e.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:0e.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:0e.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:1d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:1d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:1d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:1d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 07)
16:1e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 07)
16:1e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 07)
16:1e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 07)
16:1e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 07)
16:1e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 07)
16:1e.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 07)
16:1e.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 07)
64:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E VT-d (rev 07)
64:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers (rev 07)
64:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E IOxAPIC Configuration Registers (rev 07)
64:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:0a.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:0a.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:0a.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:0a.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:0a.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:0a.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LM Channel 1 (rev 07)
64:0a.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LMS Channel 1 (rev 07)
64:0a.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LMDP Channel 1 (rev 07)
64:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DECS Channel 2 (rev 07)
64:0b.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LM Channel 2 (rev 07)
64:0b.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LMS Channel 2 (rev 07)
64:0b.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LMDP Channel 2 (rev 07)
64:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:0c.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:0c.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller (rev 07)
64:0c.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LM Channel 1 (rev 07)
64:0c.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LMS Channel 1 (rev 07)
64:0c.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LMDP Channel 1 (rev 07)
64:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DECS Channel 2 (rev 07)
64:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LM Channel 2 (rev 07)
64:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LMS Channel 2 (rev 07)
64:0d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E LMDP Channel 2 (rev 07)
b2:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E VT-d (rev 07)
b2:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers (rev 07)
b2:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E IOxAPIC Configuration Registers (rev 07)
b2:0e.0 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E KTI 0 (rev 07)
b2:0e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E UPI Registers (rev 07)
b2:0f.0 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E KTI 0 (rev 07)
b2:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E UPI Registers (rev 07)
b2:12.0 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers (rev 07)
b2:12.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers (rev 07)
b2:12.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers (rev 07)
b2:15.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers (rev 07)
b2:15.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DDRIO Registers (rev 07)
b2:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers (rev 07)
b2:16.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DDRIO Registers (rev 07)
b2:16.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers (rev 07)
b2:16.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E DDRIO Registers (rev 07)
sprout@tol:~$ sudo lshw -c network
sprout@tol:~$
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lspci` and `sudo lshw -c network`? This should reveal which specific network device is in the machine. From there, someone can offer a solution 

Comment: I've added those two outputs.

Comment: According to the User's Manual here: https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C620/MNL-1900.pdf there is a setting in the BIOS to enable/disable the onboard LAN; i.e. ethernet device. Please check and enable it. Next, re-run and post: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` So far, we see no ethernet at all. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This is going to be a challenge. The network device is not appearing in your output and the board [does not appear to support modern Ubuntu releases](https://www.supermicro.com/support/resources/OS/C622.cfm). The [spec sheet](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/x11spi-tf) says there is a "Dual LAN with 10GBase-T with Intel® X722 + X557" device, but SuperMicro does not have any drivers available for it outside of Windows. Intel does have drivers for Linux, but it'll be hit-and-miss to determine whether they're compatible or not ... 

Comment: Chili-
I made sure that the LAN was set to enabled--it was. LAN1 and LAN2 were both set to 'Legacy'. I switched LAN2 to EFI to see if that made a difference. It did not. I got the same result when entering `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`

Comment: If the LAN devices are not detectable with any possible setting in the BIOS, then installing a driver won't bring them to life. As well, without knowing the exact device details, specifically the pci.id, something like 8086:12ab, (which we find with `lspci`) we don't even know the correct driver to install. I regret that I haven't any more helpful suggestions.

Comment: Might be DOA equipment?

Comment: I'm doing an RMA on the Mobo. Thank you all for the help!